# Consolidate multiple table in one unique table

Tags: sql, oracle, algorithm, merge, match

I have 5 tables.
Each table contains a key and column that indicates whether the keys are duplicates or not and a group key
that tell us if the key belongs to the same group.
For example,

- in Table A : 1 and 5 are duplicate because they have the same values for field p(=1) and they belon gto the same group(=1).
- in Table B : 5 and 4 are duplicate because they have the same values for field p(=1) and they belon gto the same group(=1).

It also means that 1,4 and 5 are the same because 5 is duplicate with 1 and 4.

At the end,I want to group the one that are duplicate.
The output should look like :
key,p,group

```
1,999,1
5,999,1
4,999,1
8,999,1
78,999,1
```

The row above have the same p(999) because they are all linked(same group and 1 and 5 in table A, 5 and 4 in table B,4 and 8 in table D, 5 and 78 in table E)

```
90,777,1
91,777,1
```

The row above have the same p(777) because they are linked in table E. Even if they are in the same group(the 1),
I could not linked them because they are no link with the other key.

```
10,666,1
15,666,1
21,555,1
```

The row above have different p.

```
79,222,2
80,222,2
```

Same p because linked in table A and from the same group(2)

```
81,888,3
82,888,3
```

Same p because linked in table A and from the same group(3)

```
85,111,4
```

The key is alone.

I'm looking a way to do it in sql (connect by prior does not work, some link are lost) or an algorithm.

Below a sample :

Table A

```
key,p,group
1,1,1
5,1,1
4,2,1
8,3,1
10,4,1
15,5,1
21,6,1
78,7,1
79,8,2
80,8,2
81,9,3
82,9,3
85,10,4
90,11,1
91,12,1
```

Table B

```
key,p,group
1,1,1
5,3,1
4,3,1
8,4,1
10,5,1
15,6,1
21,7,1
78,8,1
79,9,2
80,10,2
81,11,3
82,12,3
85,13,4
90,14,1
91,15,1
```

Table C

```
key,p,group
1,1,1
5,2,1
4,3,1
8,4,1
10,5,1
15,5,1
21,6,1
78,7,1
79,8,2
80,9,2
81,10,3
82,11,3
85,12,4
90,13,1
91,14,1
```

Table D

```
key,p,group
1,1,1
5,2,1
4,3,1
8,3,1
10,5,1
15,6,1
21,7,1
78,8,1
79,9,2
80,10,2
81,11,3
82,12,3
85,13,4
90,14,1
91,15,1
```

Table E

```
key,p,group
1,1,1
5,2,1
4,3,1
8,4,1
10,5,1
15,6,1
21,7,1
78,2,1
79,8,2
80,9,2
81,10,3
82,11,3
85,12,4
90,13,1
91,13,1
```

Comment: Where do these values: 999, 777, 222 etc. come from ? Are they sums ? Please explain how to get them, because it's unclear.

Comment: These values are just a random id. It's a new to help to group the duplicate.it could be 1,2... whatever.999 means all the key with 999 are duplicate.